# Pandas - transform() raises ValueError while values are strings

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I have two dataframes which I floor_divided initially and converted to strings successfully. My aim is to replace  values with "1:0" and add the ":1" to the rest, but I get an error as shown:

```
>>>df1
   ID  quantity
0 007      48.0
1 001      37.0
2 006      37.0
3 111      37.0
4 001      34.0
5 101      37.0 

>>>df2
   ID  quantity
0 001      16.0
1 006      16.0
2 111      16.0
3 001      14.0
4 101      16.0
5 111      16.0

df1_to_df2=df1('ID').floordiv(df2('ID')).astype('Int64').astype(str)
>>>df1_to_df2
     quantity
 ID              
007      <NA>  #this must be replaced by "1:0"
001         2  #":1" should be added when only a digit is there
006         2
111         2
001         2
101         2

#Then I tried this:
df1_to_df2=df1_to_df2.transform(lambda x: replace(x,'1:0') if x=='<NA>' else x+':1')

#and it raises this error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Help is needed, I do not know how to fix this in order to get the desired output below:

```
     quantity
 ID              
007      1:0
001      2:1
006      2:1
111      2:1
001      2:1
101      2:1
```

Many thanks!!!

Comment: Please share the expected output

Comment: Thanks, I added that piece too after prompting to do so.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

df1,df2 = map(lambda x: pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(x), sep='\s+', converters={'ID':str}), (s1,s2))

df = (df1.set_index('ID')//df2.set_index('ID')).fillna(0).astype(int)
df.quantity = np.where(df.quantity==0, '1:0', df.quantity.astype(str) + ':1')
df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates()

print(df)
    ID quantity
0  001      2:1
4  006      2:1
5  007      1:0
6  101      2:1
7  111      2:1
```

You could also use transform the way you want:

```
df = (df1.set_index('ID')//df2.set_index('ID')).fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)
df.quantity = df.quantity.transform(lambda x: '1:0' if x=='0' else x+':1')
```

Comment: The first approach with ```np.where()``` worked as a good work-around, but I wish the ```transform``` also worked. On the contrary, it raised the same ```ValueError``` and I have a problem to comprehend why this error is thrown even by getting rid of NaNs.

Comment: My transform works.  I've tested it.  Are you sure you aren't forgetting to specify columns?  I.e: `df['quantity'] = df['quantity'].transform(lambda x: '1:0' if x=='<NA>' else x+':1')`

Comment: yes, I am sure... and I checked all the values that accrue after floor_dividing too and I do not have anything like ```inf``` so I am not able to spot how this error is raised.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it seems that you only need to transform the column quantity: 
Could you try the following slight alteration of refering to the column and adding x.replace instead of replace

```
df1_to_df2['quantity'].transform(lambda x: x.replace(x, '1:0') if x=='<NA>' else x+':1')
```

Comment: No, I get the ValueError anyways.